# Stopping springBatch JobExecution halts steps, but job itself stuck on 'STOPPING' status

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I have a simple job set up:

```
<job id="myJob" restartable="false"
         xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
         job-repository="dbJobRepository">
        <step id="myStep">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="myReader"
                       processor="myProcessor"
                       writer="myWriter"
                       commit-interval="100">
                </chunk>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
</job>

<bean id="dbJobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
</bean>
```

The job is fired through a Quartz container process:

```
public void runHook() throws Exception {
    ...
    this.jobParameters = jobParamsBuilder.toJobParameters();
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(this.job, this.jobParameters);
    BatchStatus batchStatus = jobExecution.getStatus();
    ...
}

public void abort() {
    ...
    JobOperator jobOperator = KBeansProvider.getBean("jobOperator");
    JobRepository jobRepository = KBeansProvider.getBean("dbJobRepository");
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(this.jobBeanId,this.jobParameters);

    try {
        jobExecution.stop();
        jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getJobId());
    ...
}
```

Upon calling abort(), the execution is found and the step itself stops in a manner of seconds:

```
2012-02-13 13:59:37,566 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository] - <Parent JobExecution is stopped, so passing message on to StepExecution>
2012-02-13 13:59:37,569 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.step.ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy] - <Step interrupted through StepExecution>
2012-02-13 13:59:37,573 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] - <Encountered an error executing the step>
org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException: Job interrupted status detected.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy.checkInterrupted(ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy.java:42)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:277)
```

The step status in batch_step_execution table is set to STOPPED, as expected.
The problem is that the runHook method is blocked on:
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(this.job, this.jobParameters);
(I must use a synced jobLauncher here due to system constrains)
and the batch_job_execution entry for that job is in 'STOPPING' status.

A strange behavior to note, is that sometimes the status WILL change to STOPPED and jobLauncher.run() WILL return, but only after significant time, with minimum of 10  minutes and up to an hour or two.

This is the stacktrace of the runHook() thread:

```
MyClusteredReadyScheduler_Worker-3@8362, prio=3, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2499)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3010)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2943)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3486)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1416)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.nextRecord(RowDataDynamic.java:416)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.next(RowDataDynamic.java:395)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.close(RowDataDynamic.java:173)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:7623)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.close(ResultSetImpl.java:907)
      at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.close(DelegatingResultSet.java:152)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(JdbcUtils.java:107)
      at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doClose(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:375)
      at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:124)
      at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:83)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:297)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:255)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
      at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
      at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
```

Looking at the stacktrace it looks like the fault is somehow related to the jdbc connection,
so I'll provide some extra info that might help.

My reader extends AbstractCursorItemReader, and relevant methods include:

```
    @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            setSql(this.sql);
            this.setSaveState(false);
            this.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
            this.setIgnoreWarnings(true);
            this.setUseSharedExtendedConnection(false);
            this.setQueryTimeout(10000);
    }

    protected void cleanupOnClose() throws Exception {
                JdbcUtils.closeStatement(this.preparedStatement);
    }

    protected void openCursor(Connection con) {
                try {
                    if (isUseSharedExtendedConnection()) {
                        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
                                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
                    }
                    else {
                        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                    }

                    applyStatementSettings(preparedStatement);
                    if (this.preparedStatementSetter != null) {
                        preparedStatementSetter.setValues(preparedStatement);                           
                    }
                    preparedStatement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

                    this.rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    ProcessLogger.getLogger().debug("Executed query: " + this.rs.getStatement());
                }
}
```

The desired behavior I'm after is for the job to stop right away - or at least a short while after the step is stopped.

Comment: have you tried reproducing this error with the mysql driver outside of the entire spring batch mechanism.